# R: Mean (and sd) number of occurrences by two groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like the calculate the average (and sd) number of times Surfaces are touched during different CareType.

```
head(movsdf.rbind)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  ActivityID CareType HCWType Orientation Surface    Date       Time    
  <fct>      <fct>    <fct>   <fct>       <chr>      <date>     <time>  
1 01         IV       RN01    leftFacing  AlcOutside 0003-08-20 11:08:01
2 01         IV       RN01    leftFacing  In         0003-08-20 11:08:12
3 01         IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door       0003-08-20 11:08:12
4 01         IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door       0003-08-20 11:08:18
5 01         IV       RN01    leftFacing  Other      0003-08-20 11:08:22
6 01         IV       RN01    leftFacing  Table      0003-08-20 11:10:26
```

Some example data

```
movs.rbind<-data.frame(CareType=rep(c("IV","Rounds"),each=50),Surface=rep(c("Table","Chair"), each=50),ActivityID=rep(1:5,each=20))


#This gives me the number of each type of surface touched in each activityID grouped by care type but I'd like to know the mean number of times any surfaces are touched per care type
t<-aggregate(data=movsdf.rbind,Surface~CareType+ActivityID,function(x) NROW(x))
```

To find the mean number of surfaces touched
 I do:

```
aggregate(data=t,Surface~CareType,mean)
```

surely there's an elegant summarise function in dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly simple `dplyr` solution:

First group by CareType and ActivityID (the order is important as each `summarise` call strips the last of the groupings).

Then use `summarise` to count the number of touches by CareType and ActivityID, and summarise again to get your summary statistics by CareType only.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1<-data.frame(CareType=rep(c("IV","Rounds"),each=50),Surface=rep(c("Table","Chair"), each=50),ActivityID=rep(1:5,each=20))


df1 %>% group_by(CareType, ActivityID) %>% 
  summarise(touches = n()) %>% 
  summarise(mean_touches = mean(touches),
            sd_touches = sd(touches))

## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  CareType mean_touches sd_touches
#  <fct>           <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 IV               16.7       5.77
#2 Rounds           16.7       5.77
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I couldn't think straight yesterday.

Comment: No problem we all have days like that! Not sure why you ended up getting so many downvotes on this q btw